# Pasting Together Relatively Open Sets

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I'm sometimes in the situation where I have a cover $X = A \cup B$ of a topological space, and I have sets $U \subseteq A$ and $V \subseteq B$, each relatively open. In this case I would like to show that $U \cup V$ is open in $X$. I was able to prove a relatively weak sufficient condition for this to work:

*Proposition.* Let $X = A \cup B$, where $A$ and $B$ are closed in $X$. If $U$ is open in $A$ and $V$ is open in $B$, then if $U \cap B = V \cap A$, then $U \cup V$ is open in $X$.

Can we weaken these conditions any further? In particular, is it necessary to assume the cover $X = A \cup B$ is closed?

Comment: Isn't it trivial that if $A$ and $B$ are open, then $U$ and $V$ are open iff they are relatively open in $A$ and $B$ (resp.)?

Comment: I think OP meant that $U$ is relatively open in $A$, but that $A$ need not be open in $X$.  (Assuming the weak definition of "cover" not meaning "open cover.")

Comment: For a counter-example to the necessity, I think you can take $X = \Bbb{R}$, $A = (-\infty, 1)$, $B = (-1, \infty)$, $U = (-\infty, -1)$ and $V = (1, \infty)$. Then neither $A$ or $B$ is closed in $X$, but all the conditions in the second sentence of your proposition hold.

Comment: I think there is a typo in the first paragraph of the question: shouldn't $U \cup B$ read $U \cup V$?

Comment: It seems necessary to have $A$ and $B$ overlap. What if you require only $U\cap V\subset A\cap B$?

Comment: Maybe let $X=A\cup B$  with $U,V$ relatively open in $A,B$ (resp). If $U\cap \partial U\subset V$ and $V\cap \partial V\subset U$, then $U\cup V$ is open in $X$?